# node doesn't work when run through PHP

Tags: php, node.js, npm

I'm trying to create a simple PHP script that runs webpack. It runs fine when I run it in the terminal, but gives me memory errors when I run it from PHP. This is what my code looks like:

PHP:

`shell_exec('webpack -p --config /home/[username]/config/config.production.js 2>&1');`

results in this:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[20920:0x405ede0]      786 ms: Scavenge 40.6 (63.1) -> 31.1 (66.6) MB, 3.4 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure 
[20920:0x405ede0]      867 ms: Scavenge 45.2 (66.6) -> 35.6 (67.1) MB, 8.5 / 0.0 ms  allocation failure 


<--- JS stacktrace --->
Cannot get stack trace in GC.
FATAL ERROR: NewSpace::Rebalance Allocation failed - process out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x8d04bc [node]
 3: v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(char const*, bool) [node]
 4: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xa7006b [node]
 6: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::Evacuate() [node]
 7: v8::internal::MarkCompactCollector::CollectGarbage() [node]
 8: v8::internal::Heap::MarkCompact() [node]
 9: v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
10: v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
11: v8::internal::Factory::NewByteArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [node]
12: v8::internal::TranslationBuffer::CreateByteArray(v8::internal::Factory*) [node]
13: v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::PopulateDeoptimizationData(v8::internal::Handle) [node]
14: v8::internal::compiler::CodeGenerator::FinalizeCode() [node]
15: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineImpl::FinalizeCode() [node]
16: v8::internal::compiler::PipelineCompilationJob::FinalizeJobImpl() [node]
17: v8::internal::Compiler::FinalizeCompilationJob(v8::internal::CompilationJob*) [node]
18: v8::internal::OptimizingCompileDispatcher::InstallOptimizedFunctions() [node]
19: v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [node]
20: v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
21: 0x24ffb0c842fd
```

`free -m` gives me this:

```
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         31956      29146       2810         51        947      24470
-/+ buffers/cache:       3728      28228
Swap:         5999          0       5999
```

`vmstat` gives me this:

```
    procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0     64 2877076 969764 25058456    0    0     0    10    0    0  0  0 99  0  0
```

It doesn't seem there are any glaring memory issues to me? 
If I put the webpack command into a npm script, and run that from PHP instead, I'll get this error: (but running the npm script from the terminal is fine too.)

```
npm ERR! path /home/[username]
npm ERR! code ENOMEM
npm ERR! errno -12
npm ERR! syscall scandir
npm ERR! ENOMEM: not enough memory, scandir '/home/[username]'
glob error { Error: ENOMEM: not enough memory, scandir '/home/[username]'
  errno: -12,
  code: 'ENOMEM',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: '/home/[username]' }
```

I'm assuming this is just the same error just thrown by Node instead. When I try to run any other NPM command from PHP (like `npm list`) I'll also get the ENOMEM error, which leads me to believe it's only a node issue and not anything else.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on or why this might be happening?

Versions:

`nvm ls`

```
->      v9.11.1
default -> node (-> v9.11.1)
node -> stable (-> v9.11.1) (default)
stable -> 9.11 (-> v9.11.1) (default)
iojs -> N/A (default)
lts/* -> lts/carbon (-> N/A)
lts/argon -> v4.9.1 (-> N/A)
lts/boron -> v6.14.1 (-> N/A)
lts/carbon -> v8.11.1 (-> N/A)
```

PHP Version: 5.5.35

Linux Dist: CentOS release 6.9 (Final)

`shell_exec('env');` gives me the following:

```
[0] => SERVER_SIGNATURE=
[1] => HTTP_X_HTTPS=1
[2] => SSL_TLS_SNI=www.[mydomain.com]
[3] => UNIQUE_ID=Wt5Y@K33-aQAAGEyFT8AAAAR
[4] => HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36
[5] => SERVER_PORT=443
[6] => PHPRC=/home/[username]/public_html
[7] => HTTP_HOST=www.[mydomain.com]
[8] => DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/[username]/public_html
[9] => SCRIPT_FILENAME=/home/[username]/public_html/template-files/scripts/run-webpack.php
[10] => HTTPS=on
[11] => REQUEST_URI=/template-files/scripts/run-webpack.php
[12] => SCRIPT_NAME=/template-files/scripts/run-webpack.php
[13] => SCRIPT_URI=https://www.[mydomain.com]/template-files/scripts/run-webpack.php
[14] => HTTP_CONNECTION=keep-alive
[15] => REMOTE_PORT=7941
[16] => PATH=/bin:/home/[username]/.nvm/versions/node/v9.11.1/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/[username]/perl5/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/home/[username]/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/[username]/bin
[17] => SCRIPT_URL=/template-files/scripts/run-webpack.php
[18] => CONTEXT_PREFIX=
[19] => PWD=/home/[username]/public_html/template-files/scripts
[20] => SERVER_ADMIN=webmaster@[mydomain.com]
[21] => REQUEST_SCHEME=https
[22] => REDIRECT_STATUS=200
[23] => TZ=America/Los_Angeles
[24] => HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.9
[25] => HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
[26] => REMOTE_ADDR=[myIP]
[27] => SHLVL=1
[28] => SERVER_NAME=www.[mydomain.com]
[29] => SERVER_SOFTWARE=Apache
[30] => QUERY_STRING=
[31] => SERVER_ADDR=[myIP]
[32] => GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
[33] => HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS=1
[34] => SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
[35] => HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=max-age=0
[36] => HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate, br
[37] => REQUEST_METHOD=GET
[38] => HTTP_COOKIE=_ga=[cookieID…etc]
[39] => CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/home/[username]/public_html
[40] => _=/bin/env
```

`echo shell_exec('bash -c "ulimit -a"');`
Results in this:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 127717
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 16384
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 400
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 1048576
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Please let me know if i can provide any more information about this issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try directly in your terminal? How do you run this PHP script (CLI , web, cron?) What is the output of `shell_exec ('node --version')`?

Comment: See if this thread helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206721/npm-does-not-run-when-called-through-nginx-php-fpm-exec/46207424#46207424

Comment: @Nek I run it by just hitting the URL on the web. Directly in the terminal everything works as planned. `shell_exec ('node --version')` actually outputs the version number (9.11.1).

Comment: @TarunLalwani Thanks, it looks similar but I have had some PATH issues in the past so I already made sure to check that my PATH was defined properly.

Comment: Please add the output of `shell_exec('env')`

Comment: @TarunLalwani added.

Comment: Is PHP running as a different user than when you run it from the terminal?  PHP or the web server might have different ulimits in place that restrict the amount of memory that can be used.

Comment: You are running this PHP CLI or PHP web? Please clear that as well. Also I would run it with `shell_exec('NODE_DEBUG=fs,module,gc webpack -p --config /home/[username]/config/config.production.js 2>&1');` and get additional log before the failure

Comment: Check your php max memory usage setting. I'd assume that the php process thats calling node is whats going out of memory

Comment: @mcheah What is the output of this PHP script, run in the same environment that you are trying to execute node under? `<pre><?php echo shell_exec('bash -c "ulimit -a"') ?></pre>`

Comment: What @TobyOkeke said. Sounds like your php `memory_limit` could be too low. The default is 128MB (http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) but Webpack likely needs more than that.

Comment: @drew010 - PHP is running as the same user according to `shell_exec('whoami');`. @TarunLalawni I'm running PHP web. That command that you gave me gives ~9000 lines, all of which appear to be loading a different node module. 
@TobyOkeke @Randy The php max meory is 512MB. I assume that's good enough? 
@cdhowie the output of `bash -c "ulimit -a"` is now in the post.

Comment: @mcheah Does this output differ from `ulimit -a` in your shell? In particular, the "virtual memory" line.

Comment: @cdhowie yes! in the shell, the virtual memory is `unlimited`. Other changes are: `max user processes: 64`, and `open files: 1048576`

Comment: @mcheah And both are being run as the same user?

Comment: @cdhowie yes according to `whoami`

Comment: @mcheah There's some nonsense going on in PHP or the HTTP service then. It's likely calling `setrlimit()` somewhere to limit the amount of memory that child processes may consume.

Comment: @cdhowie I was able to get it working! There was an obscure setting in WHM called "Configure Apache RLimits" where I could set `RLimitMEM` . The setting was disabled but the recommended setting was 2996MB so I enabled it and it started working. There is also an `RLimitMEM` in my httpd.conf file which was set to 3141MB so I don't know why the WHM change would have done anything but I'm not complaining. If you want to put that in an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @mcheah Glad you were able to locate the problem! I've written an answer that should be generic enough to guide others facing a similar issue (particularly since the question doesn't mention WHM).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the diagnostic information you've given, the web server environment is operating with a memory limit (likely via the `setrlimit()` system call).  This call allows a process to constrain how much memory it or its children are allowed to allocate.

You will need to locate and change the relevant setting to raise or disable the memory limit.